# Manipulating the current document from an Add-on SDK panel

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am writing a Firefox add-on using the new SDK that does 5 very simple jobs. They are roughly related, so I would prefer a single add-on with a dropdown menu which I have implemented in a Panel.

I am working my way through the new SDK documentation, but can't find a direct solution. I find I can add a panel, but I cannot see how to manipulate the document in the current tab.

This is possible, isn't it? Using the global `document` doesn't work as presumably refers to the panel, or at least not to the document I am viewing.

So, how do I access the document from an add-on panel?

Comment: There are now two different things which might be referred to as SDK's for Firefox add-ons. It would help to be clear as to which you are using. The older one is called the [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK). Usually, it would be assumed that is the one that you are talking about (which would be consistent with the tags you have used). However, at this point it would not be considered "new".  The *new* one, is "[WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions)".  You said "new" twice. Are you talking about the Add-on SDK, or WebExtensions?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is that you don't access web content from your main JavaScript code. You interact with the document (web content) in the browser's tab using [Content Scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts).  You can have the content script [pass messages to your main script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#Communicating_with_the_add-on).

[MDN summarizes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts) the principals of using content scripts with the SDK as follows:

> Content scripts can be one of the more confusing aspects of working
>   with the SDK, but you're very likely to have to use them. There are
>   five basic principles:
>
> - the add-on's main code, including "main.js" and other modules in    "lib", can use the SDK [high-level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs) and [low-level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs) APIs, but
>     can't    access web content directly
> - content scripts [can't use the SDK's APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Two_Types_of_Scripts#API_Access_for_Add-on_Code_and_Content_Scripts) (no access to globals exports, require) but can access web content
> - SDK APIs that use content scripts, like [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) and [tabs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs), provide functions that enable the add-on's main code to
>     load content scripts into web pages
> - content scripts can be loaded in as strings, but are more often stored as separate files under the add-on's "data" directory. jpm
>     doesn't make a "data" directory by default, so you must add it and put
>     your content scripts in there.
> - a message-passing API allows the main code and content scripts to communicate with each other

Exactly how you would do what you are wanting is unclear because you have not provided a clear description of what you are doing. However, it almost sounds like you could implement what you want using the [context-menu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/context-menu). The context menu is one of the ways to attach a content script to the current tab and may provide you with the dropdown menu feel which you desired (although it is part of the context menu, not a dropdown menu).